# Flash Form Validation : ComboBox Validation : AS3 : Flash CS3

Tags: flash, forms, combobox, validation

I'm doing a simple validation for a flash form created.  It's working fine with text filed and Radio groups.  But Having issue with ComboBox.  Anybody able to help?  Thanks in advance.

Is it possible to write as ,

} else if (!placeopCombo.selected) {
 status_txt.text = "Please choose Place of Purchase";

---

My code is below

if(!nameTxt.length) {
 status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
  } else if (!emailTxt.length) {
  status_txt.text = "Please enter your email";
 } else if (!mobileTxt.length) {
  status_txt.text = "Please enter your mobile number";

} else {

//do the submitting

Answer (score 0):

The **selectedItem** property is null until you select something so you should be able to do this:

```
} else if (!placeopCombo.selectedItem) { status_txt.text = "Please choose Place of Purchase";
```

Aternatively you can check if the index or label are different to an initial/default value

```
} else if (placeopCombo.selectedIndex != defaultIndex) { status_txt.text = "Please choose Place of
```

Don't know if it's handy at this stage, but also have a look at the [Yahoo! Form components](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/form/).

Comment: Hi George, Thanks for reply.  But I think, ComboBox.selectedItem will maintain the default selected value.  I just print that value for confirming.  It's returning the first value in the combo box. Thanks for Yahoo FDN anyway..